# Regex using from inside of quotation

Tags: php, regex, string

This is my current regex attempt:

```
$input_lines = 'Data1("begin    Data2(hey); end", "hi");';    
preg_match_all("/(.*?)[(](.*?)[)][;]/", $input_lines, $output_array);
```

I want this regex to get:

```
"begin    Data2(hey); end", "hi"
```

On the third array, but it just gets:

```
"begin    Data2(hey
```

I want to not get anything inside of these double quotes (not close when we have `);` inside of `" "`).

Comment: `$input_lines` seem to be invalid syntax, it'll throw errors.

Comment: Check it into (http://www.phpliveregex.com/) . i am using this website

Comment: @Justmyhope2016 Do you want to match `"begin    Data2(hey); end", "hi"` as 1 entire match or do you want 2 separate matches `"begin    Data2(hey); end"` and `"hi"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could extend your regular expression so that it first checks if there is a double quote immediately after the opening bracket, and if so to require that there is one just before the closing bracket:

```
$input_lines = "Data1(\"begin    Data2(hey); end\", \"hi\");";    
preg_match_all('/(.*?)[(](".*?"|.*?)[)];/', $input_lines, $output_array);
print_r ($output_array);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array (
        [0] => Data1("begin    Data2(hey); end", "hi");
    )
[1] => Array (
        [0] => Data1
    )
[2] => Array (
        [0] => "begin    Data2(hey); end", "hi"
    )
)
```

Probably you'll want to also have this working with single quotes, so you would add a possibility for that:

```
$input_lines = "Data1('begin    Data2(hey); end', 'hi');";    
preg_match_all('/(.*?)[(](".*?"|\'.*?\'|.*?)[)];/', $input_lines, $output_array);
print_r ($output_array);
```

Then, you would also want to deal correctly with escaped quotes inside the input data, so you would extend it to this:

```
$input_lines = "Data1('begin    Data2(\'hey\'); end', 'hi');";    
preg_match_all('/(.*?)[(](".*?(?:[\\\\]".*?)*"|\'.*?(?:[\\\\]\'.*?)*\'|.*?)[)];/',
               $input_lines, $output_array);
print_r ($output_array);
```

Output would be:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array (
        [0] => Data1('begin    Data2(\'hey\'); end', 'hi');
    )
[1] => Array (
        [0] => Data1
    )
[2] => Array (
        [0] => 'begin    Data2(\'hey\'); end', 'hi'
    )
)
```

Note that this way you will also still match strings that do not contain such quotes, e.g.

```
$input_lines = "Data1(mydata);";
```

Would still match and give expected results.

Comment: if i use (Data1('begin    Data2('hey'); end', 'hi'); )  - add qutation in Data2, will stop after data 2 and now show the end and hi !!! this is my problem !

Comment: That example seems invalid syntax, the innermost quotes should be escaped, like this "Data1('begin Data2(\'hey\'); end', 'hi');". If that is what you want to parse, I will update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a simple regex to match everything(`.` match anything except new line; `*` between 0 and more times; Also note it's greedy) between two quotes, e.g.

```
$input_lines = 'Data1("begin    Data2(hey); end", "hi");';  
preg_match('/(".*")/', $input_lines, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```